# Ruby on rails. Many to many categories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, categories, rails-i18n, ransack

I am struggling with choosing the best way of modeling categories in my project.

Users create gigs, and each gig can have multiple genres. 
Genres must be searchable with ransack and translatable.

Here is what I've tried:

Ive read that `actastaggableon` gem and ransack don't play well together if searching multiple tags. Plus, I won't need to dynamically create new genres.

I have tried `<%= form.input :genre,  :collection => [t('genre.alternative'), t('genre.blues') etc etc... multiple: true` and a `genre:string` attribute in my gig model, which works with searches but only in the language in which it was saved.

Making a genre model and using each genre's ID with a `genre_id:integer` attribute in my gig model works but doesn't allow multiple genres to be saved.

Is there any way of adding multiple ID's to a model attribute?
Are there any methods of doing this that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 1):

You need a **join table** allowing a many-to-many relationship between Gig and Genre.

```
Genre
  has_many :gig_genres
  has_many :gigs, :through => :gig_genres

Gig
  has_many :gig_genres
  has_many :genres, :through => :gig_genres

GigGenre
  belongs_to :gig
  belongs_to :genre
```

Answer (score 1):

Since a User has many gigs,add `has_many :gigs` to your User Model and then a `belongs_to :user` in your Gig Model. You'd want to add a `user_id:integer` attribute for your Gig table in order to establish the relationship.

Also, since a Gig has many generes, the same steps would apply. Add a `has_many :genres` in your Gig Model and add `belong_to :gig` in your Genre Model. You'd want to add a `gig_id:integer` to your Genre table in order to establish this relationship.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

In the end I did a mix of the other two answers.

Gig model + Genre model with a

```
def change
  create_table :genres_gigs, :id => false do |t|
    t.integer :genre_id
    t.integer :gig_id
  end
end
```

migration.

I used this page as a guide, which also helped with views and controllers.
http://habtmexample.herokuapp.com/instructions